# Python: Using AND and OR with .FIND() method

Tags: python, string

imagine I type the following code into the interpreter:

```
var1 = 'zuuzuu'
```

now suppose i type:

```
var1.find('a')
```

the interpreter returns -1. which i understand because the substring has not been found. but please help me understand this:

```
var1.find('a' or 'z') #case 1
```

returns -1

but

```
var1.find('a' and 'z') #case 2
```

returns 0

According to the logic in my head the interpreter should return -1 for case 2 because the substrings 'a' AND 'z' are NOT located in the string. While in case 1, 0 should be returned since 'z' is a substring.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expression `'a' or 'z'` always yields `'a'`. Expression `'a' and 'z'` always yields `'z'`. It's not some kind of DSL for making queries into containers, it's a simple boolean expression (and `find` is called with its result). If you want to say "is there 'a' or 'z' in the string", you need to do

```
var1.find('a') != -1 or var.find('z') != -1
```

And for the second one (both 'a' and 'z' in the string):

```
var1.find('a') != -1 and var.find('z') != -1
```

Comment: Or: `any(var1.find(i) for i in ('a', 'z'))` resp. `all(var1.find(i) for i in ('a', 'z'))`

Comment: or `'a' in var1 or 'z' in var1`

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `find` method does not in fact support `or` and `and`, it only supports querying for a string.

So, what is really going on? Well, it turns out that `or` and `and` are operators that can be performed on strings.

```
'a' and 'z' --> 'z'
'a' or 'z'  --> 'a'
```

So there you have it, you're basically just searching for `'a'` and `'z'` as normal.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def count_tokens(text):
   
    #Tokenizes the given text and returns a dictionary with the count of each distinct token.
   
    # First, split the text into individual words
    words = text.split()

    # Next, create an empty dictionary to hold the token counts
    token_counts = {}

    # Loop over the words and count how many times each one appears
    for word in words:
        if word in token_counts:
            token_counts[word] += 1
        else:
            token_counts[word] = 1

    # Finally, return the token counts dictionary
    return token_counts

text = "This is a clock. This is only a clock."
counts = count_tokens(text)
print(counts)


### stopword function
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def count_tokens(text):
   
    #Tokenizes the given text, removes stopwords, and returns a dictionary with the count of each distinct token.

    # First, split the text into individual words
    words = text.split()

    # Next, remove stopwords from the words
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    words = [word for word in words if word.lower() not in stop_words]

    # Next, create an empty dictionary to hold the token counts
    token_counts = {}

    # Loop over the words and count how many times each one appears
    for word in words:
        if word in token_counts:
            token_counts[word] += 1
        else:
            token_counts[word] = 1

    # Finally, return the token counts dictionary
    return token_counts

text = "This is a clock. This is only a clock."
counts = count_tokens(text)
print(counts)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).