# Is there a way to find specific character in string list python?

Tags: python, string, list, find

I have a list which contains string values taht represents calculations. From them I want to get a specific character, let's say plus and minus signs.

I tried using `var1.find('a') != -1 or var.find('z') != -1` as suggested here [Python: Using AND and OR with .FIND() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868891/python-using-and-and-or-with-find-method), but I'm still getting -1 when I try '-'.

Example:

```
lists = ["22 + 13", "4500 - 2"]
for list in lists :
  if (list.find('+') or (list.find('-')) != -1) :
    signpos =  list.find("+") or list.find("-")
    print(signpos)
  else:
    print('Error')
```

I get `3` aand `-1` as results, where the desire output should be `3` and `5`.

What I'm not seeing?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, you're replacing the built-in function with the same name.

Comment: It's an example the original it's not named list

Comment: I dont think this line is doing what you think it does: `if (list.find('+') or (list.find('-')) != -1) :`. Seems to me, it checks if True or False is not equal to -1, which will always be true. It’s equivalent to `if True` from what im seeing

Comment: @Barmar there is no function named list. `list` is a class, not a function.

Comment: So... how do I use the find() with a logical properly? @Anonymous4045

Comment: @Anonymous4045 Classes are used as functions, e.g. `my_list = list(something)`

Comment: The line `list.find('+') or (list.find('-')) != -1` is **not** the same as `list.find('a') != -1 or list.find('z') != -1`

Comment: @Barmar no lol, that’s called a cunstructer. It creates an instance of the list class.

Comment: @Anonymous4045 For this purpose, it doesn't really matter. It's a built-in that you shouldn't redefine.

Comment: Also, why are you naming it `list` in `for list in lists:`? Kind of gets confusing when it's not actually a list, but a string. The `list.find(val)` returns an `int`, the position of the value. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195322/pythons-logical-operator-and) for what happens if you use logical operators with `int`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others suggested, don't use `list` as a variable name. It is a type.

```
lists = ["22 + 13", "4500 - 2"]
for string in lists:
  signPos = None

  if "+" in string:
    signPos = string.find("+")
  elif "-" in string:
    signPos = string.find("-")
  else:
    print('Error')
    
  print(signPos)

# Output
# 3
# 5
```

Comment: I would make it a function

Comment: This may throw an exception if "signPos" wasn't set but should be printed. Better preset "signPos" with something like -1

Comment: I'd made it a function too but I don't want to get too far away from OP's example

Answer (score 0):

```
signpos =  list.find("+") or list.find("-")
```

If the string does not have a plus sign, the first `find()` call will return -1 which is a non-false value, so the second `find()` will not be executed, and signpos will be assigned -1.

This probably isn't what you wanted.

Comment: I’m curious, did you run that and it worked? Looks like it will just assign either True or False

Comment: @Anonymous4045 The expression `A or B` returns the value of A if it is truthy, otherwise it returns the value of B.  It does not necessarily return true/false.